# List of all stream sources and whether they are ordered or unordered

Tags: java, java-stream

Does anyone have, or know of, a list of all possible stream sources, e.g. collections (including specific types), arrays, functions, I/O, etc, and whether they produce an ordered or unordered stream?

For example, Arrays.stream in the API does not specify whether the stream returned is ordered or unordered? Also, what about the CharSequence chars() method, and data structures such as TreeSet?

Comment: You should assume least surprise. If the input and resulting collection is ordered, the result is order (provided you didn't use parallel stream) If the input or resulting collection is not ordered, the result is not ordered.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, even if stream is parallel. Actually the ordering is the most crucial for parallel stream.

Comment: @TagirValeev can you elaborate on what you mean? When you use parallelStream the order of completion is not deterministic.

Comment: @TagirValeev Ok, it appears that `.collect(Collectors.toList())` returns the same order whether parallel or not which is good. My warning about parallel() doesn't appear to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams are implemented sanely according to the principle of least surprise in all sources by the JDK.

This means that if a stream source has any sort of sensical order, then the stream is correspondingly sensically ordered.  The only major sources of unordered streams in the JDK, therefore, are from `HashSet`s, `HashMap` views, and `Random`.

Every other stream that "should" be ordered is ordered: `CharStream.chars()`, `LinkedHashSet.stream()`, `Files.lines`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I found this list [here][1]
I think it can help answering your question:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th align="left"></th>
<th align="center"><code>ORDERED</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>DISTINCT</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>SORTED</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>SIZED</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>NONULL</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>IMMUTABLE</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>CONCURRENT</code></th>
<th align="center"><code>SUBSIZED</code></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>Stream.of</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>Arrays.asList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>HashSet</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ArrayList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ArrayDeque</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ArrayBlockingQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ArrayDeque</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ConcurrentLinkedDeque</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ConcurrentLinkedQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>DelayQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>CopyOnWriteArraySet</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>CopyOnWriteArrayList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>ConcurrentSkipListSet</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>LinkedBlockingDeque</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>LinkedBlockingQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>LinkedHashSet</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>LinkedList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>Stack</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>RoleUnresolvedList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>RoleList</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>PriorityQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>PriorityBlockingQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>LinkedTransferQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>SynchronousQueue</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>TreeSet</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><code>Vector</code></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"><code>I</code></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I - Injects.

- this the html code of the table. I couldn't copy and paste it as a table in the post editor. you can run it then copy and paste it or, you can check the source website.
  [1]: https://github.com/stavalfi/lectures/tree/master/Java%20Streams%20-%20Series